# Printing Sum of first n Integers

Tags: python

According to me this code below should print the sum of first `n` integers but it is giving me name error on line `5`. How do I fix this ?

```
def printsum(n):
    n = int(raw_input())
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        j = i + 1
        doublesum = i + j - n
    total = doublesum / 2
    print total
```

Comment: The variables `j` or `i` do not exist outside of the scope of `printsum`. I suggest taking some time to read over this [nice article by Sebastian Raschka](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_scope_and_namespaces.html) to better understand Python namespaces.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: @Devesh, your indentation appears confusing, and probably wrong.  Is this your actual code, including the indentation?

Comment: See the article I linked to @DeveshLohumi.

Comment: @DaveCosta Fixed it, Yes, straight from my IDLE.

Comment: Are you trying use the formula `sum(1..n) = n(n+1)/2`? If so, you don't need a loop. If you are trying to explicitly sum up the range, then you want something like `j=0; for i in range(1,n+1): j += i`.

Comment: @chepner Yes, I was trying to use that but in a creative way.

Comment: @DeveshLohumi An unrelated remark: [Are you sure, you as a beginner want to learn Python2.x?](https://pythonclock.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables `i` and `j` are local to the function `printsum`. Simply return the values from the function and use said values to do your calculation.

Comment: Declared j and doublesum outside the function, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code copy and past. Because issue may be indentation

```
def printsum(n):
    n = int(raw_input())
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        j = i + 1
        doublesum = i + j - n
        total = doublesum / 2
    print total
    return;
```

Your logic is make me confused too.

Comment: Tried this. This gives the same output as input. Also why are you returning the function at the end ?

Comment: The return statement is used when a function is ready to return a value to its caller.